# Process State Diagram : Transition of a process from Suspend Wait to Suspend Ready?

Tags: operating-system

Lets say a process is in `Suspend Wait` state waiting for its i/o to complete . Whenever its `i/o` gets completed the state of the process changes to `Suspend Ready`.

Will the process inside `Ready but Suspended` state be considered to be in the `Ready queue` and will it participate in the `process scheduling competition` along  with other processes which are already in the `Ready Queue`.

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: Generally asking , not specific OS . Basically this qs came out of the OS theory and the basis of its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The process will be in the suspend ready queue from which only the medium term scheduler will pick up and put it in the ready queue. From there the short term scheduler will pick it and give to the CPU for processing.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-notes-operating-system-process-management-introduction/

Comment: this is wrong. there is no such thing as mid term schedular at least not in Linux, Windows and mac.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that you need to understand that **computer science is not mathematics** and lot of terms that we use often are not clearlly defined. same is the case with the process states you describe above.

that being said, generally when a process completes its IO then it moves directlly to ready queue

Comment: And process states are entirely system specific.

Comment: Yes I know. That’s why I said generally.